# For... of loop returning unexpected undefined

Tags: javascript

I am doing a simple for...of loop. I do not understand why I get different results when I console.log the output of the loop and when I print it to screen.

```
const list = document.getElementById('list');
const results = [1, 2, 5];
let listItems;

for (let r of results) {
  listItems = listItems + `<li>${r}</li>`;
  console.log(r);
}

list.innerHTML = listItems;

//// console.log returns 1, 2, 5

//// in the DOM, i get undefined, 1, 2, 5
```

You can try it in my [codepen](http://codepen.io/akmur/pen/WoXPpO).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `listItems` in initially `undefined`.

```js
let listItems;
console.log(listItems); // undefined
```

Initialize it to the empty string, or use array joining:

```js
let listItems = '';
for (let r of [1, 2, 5])
  listItems += `<li>${r}</li>`;
console.log(listItems);

listItems = [];
for (let r of [1, 2, 5])
  listItems.push(`<li>${r}</li>`);
console.log(listItems.join(''));
```

Answer (score 2):

Because in the first iteration of the loop, `listItems` is `undefined`. Give it an empty string:

```
let listItems = '';
```

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pNdGWa)

Answer (score 1):

It's because `listItems` is `undefined`, and when you add a string 'foo' to variable which is `undefined` the result is 'undefinedfoo`.

Correct version is below:

```
const list = document.getElementById('list');
const results = [1, 2, 5];
let listItems = '';

for (let r of results) {
   listItems = listItems + `<li>${r}</li>`;
   console.log(r);
}

list.innerHTML = listItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because letItems is undefined the first time. It only has a value the second time around, after you set it in the loop.

Do this:

```
let listItems = '';
```